# Calling TextBox from MainWindow in Static Method

Tags: c#, wpf, static

If have a WPF Application with several Controls (TextBox).

What iam trying to do is calling on of that Textbox in a static Method:

```
private static void Transiever(object sender, ReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

            FunkTasterServiceClient client = new FunkTasterServiceClient();

            client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(HERE I WANT TO CALL THE TEXTBOX (serviceURL.Text),
            client.Endpoint.Address.Identity, client.Endpoint.Address.Headers);

            client.GetReceivedTelegram(e.Telegram.ToString());
    }
```

But it is not possible. I tried to create a new Instance of Mainwindow to call that textbox. but got Error:

```
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

How can i call the textbox safely? Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot call a textbox from a static method because textbox is an instance object. You can pass the textbox to the static method from the calling method of the static method if it is not a static method itself.

Comment: Also, it is possible that you are calling the static method through an event handler due to which it is on a separate thread and not the main thread. It is not possible to instantiate a UI component on any thread except the main thread.

Comment: Even if you are able to create a new instance of window in your static method, it will be of no use to you since you would not get the value of the textbox from user input as this would be a different textbox.

Comment: Where is the method written? In code-behind file or in other class file?

Comment: the method is written in code behind

Answer (score 0):

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {                         
            ///Do what you what ever you want here...e.g Invoke the textbox
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is truly unclear why you would need to directly access the textbox and not simply get the information it has within it. I believe that is the case.

Below is how to get at the information in the textbox from another thread. It is done by binding to a property to a *viewmodel* and exposing the viewmodel as a static which is accessible from your static method; which that process can get to the current data held in the text box.

Follow these steps to access the ServiceUrl information found in the textbox.

1. Create a ViewModel with a string property for `ServiceUrl` which adheres to INotifyPropetyChanged and instantiate it on the mainpage.
2. Bind you textbox Text property to `ServiceUrl` as a two way binding.
3. On your class which holds your `Transiever` call, create a `static` property reference to the ViewModel class used in step1.
4. When appropriate (such as after the initial instance creation of the VM) load the static property created in step 3.
5. Then when static `Transiever` runs, access the static ViewModel's `ServiceUrl` property and extract the data as needed.

---

Two things of note

1. *Did you mean to use the name Transceiver instead of `Transiever`*?
2. If you need a refresher on a quick way to bind using the MVVM methodology, check out my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) for help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of this can be done is create a static reference to the window and access the TextBox through the static window reference object. Something like this:

```
public partial class MyWindow
{    
    public static System.Windows.Window windowRef;

    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        windowRef = this;
    }

    private static void Transiever(object sender, ReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        FunkTasterServiceClient client = new FunkTasterServiceClient();

        client.Endpoint.Address = 
            new EndpointAddress(new Uri((windowRef.serviceURL.Text),
        client.Endpoint.Address.Identity, client.Endpoint.Address.Headers);

        client.GetReceivedTelegram(e.Telegram.ToString());
    }    
}
```

I have not tried it but I think this should work. Please let me know if it does not.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. i cant call windowRed.serviceURL. Doesnt find the textbox..